# Controlling the security Principle passed on a EJB call

Tags: java, ejb

I am working on a large existing EJB 1.1 application that current does its own sercurity and has no EJB managed security.

I am trying to move to a more standard solution in small steps, and so I want to start controlling the security Principle being passed to the EJB. I am not going to be able to change the current login or security framework, so I don't belive I can move to JAAS at the present time.

Once I have created a java.security.Principle where do I store it so it is passed in my ejb calles and avalable from context.getCallerPrincipal()?

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487224/how-to-handle-dynamic-role-or-username-changes-in-jsf

Answer (score 3):

Java EE security is a bit a all-or-nothing thing. You are supposed to use Java EE authentication mechanism to have the security context correctly set. As you can see, the [`EJBContext`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html) that you can obtain through injection is read-only.

The only standard way I'm aware of to change the security context, is using things like `@RunAs` (See [an example](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/testing-security-example.html)), but it's very inflexible. You can not pass credential dynamically.

There are some non-portable container-specific mechanism, for instance Glassfish has [`ProgrammaticLogin`](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4496/beacm?a=view). But even in this case, you need to pass the username/password, you can not just change the `Principal` on the fly.

I remember reading articles where they explained how to set the security context manually using internal API of the container, but it's of course non-portable and not supported.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer, not the answer I wanted to hear though.

Comment: >There are some non-portable container-specific mechanism, for instance Glassfish has ProgrammaticLogin - For the web layer this has been standardized in `HttpServletRequest#login` and `HttpServletRequest#authenticate`. The latter does not need username/password. Combined with a suitable JASPIC auth module (or possibly a proprietary) you can authenticate a new user (and thus change identity). You have to call this from the web layer though and doesn't work in pure EJB only.

Answer (score 1):

The new [Security API in Java EE 8](https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/java-ee-8-security-api-overview/) provides a consistent approach to Security. The `SecurityContext` abstraction spans the Servlet and EJB containers and provides methods that return the user principal.

In Java EE 5/6/7 the servlet and EJB containers implement security context objects inconsistently. For example, the servlet container provides an `HttpServletRequest` instance on which the `getUserPrincipal()` method is called to obtain the user `Principal`, and the EJB container provides the differently named `EJBContext` instance, on which the same named method is called. And likewise, to test if the user belongs to a certain role the method `isUserRole()` is called on the `HttpServletRequest` instance and the `isCallerInRole()` is called on the `EJBContext` instance.

The `SecurityContext` provides consistency across the Servlet and EJB container for obtaining this kind of information.