# web.xml: setting values from properties file

Tags: tomcat, properties, web.xml

Is it possible to set values in Tomcat's web.xml by fetching values from properties file?

e.g. I would like to have user roles settings externalized in properties file, is it possible then to do something like this:

my properties file:

```
#properties file
my.user.role=role1
```

my web.xml:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>${my.user.role}</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**Edit:**

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230717/dynamic-roles-on-a-java-ee-server) post, so I guess roles need to be set static in *web.xml*.

Answer (score 0):

You can access system environment variables. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404384/referencing-environment-variables-in-web-xml) post.

Comment: Thanx for help, but this is not what I'm looking for. As I see **<env-entry>** needs to be specified in _web.xml_. But, my goal is to externalize settings, and not to '_hard-code_' them in _web.xml_, if this is possible at all.