# Java EE authorization using Roles defined in database, in Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, authorization, jaas

I want to have authorization in my Java EE application.

Online it describes how you should define the roles in **sun-web.xml**. However I would like to have all my roles, and groups defined in a database table.

That means, when I access a method for my application, the request needs to be intercepted to see if the user is allowed in the role.

Do I need to

- create some kind of interceptor class that checks auth as user makes call to my web service method
- create a custom Login Module that fishes out the group and role data from the database when a user first logs on

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all: I would strongly suggest using standard authorization mechanisms.**

But for your use-case these standard mechanisms won't work, see this post:  [dynamic roles on a Java EE server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230717/dynamic-roles-on-a-java-ee-server)

Roles have to be declared in the web.xml or sun-web.xml.

**Frameworks**

The next thing I would look into are frameworks, that could help you with that. The link will provide you with two suggested frameworks.

**Building your own**

If you don't need it for productive purposes, I would suggest the following:

- use Filters to check for authorization and authentication: Filters a fairly easy to use ,very powerful and often used for security purposes: See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html for more information about filter.
- For the login, you could probably just stick with the standard form-based login.